# Difference in filter behaviour between Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a series of `filter` on a list in a for loop, but there are some unexpected outcome in Python 3, whereas Python 2 gave the expected outcome.

For example,

```
mylist = range(3)
for i in range(3):
    mylist = filter(lambda x: x != i, mylist)

print(list(mylist))
```

gave `[0, 1]`, but I'm expecting `[]`.

Another example is

```
mylist = range(3)
for i in range(3):
    mylist = filter(lambda x: x != i, mylist)
    print(list(mylist))
```

which gave

```
[1, 2]
[]
[]
```

but I'm expecting

```
[1, 2]
[2]
[]
```

Changing `range(3)` to `list(range(3))` doesn't change the output.

Comment: `range` is an iterator, it gets exhausted the first time through the loop and is empty afterwards -- if you change your first line to `mylist = list(range(3))` it will do as you expect

Comment: @AnthonySottile I tried and it doesn't.

Comment: oh I see you're also clobbering `mylist` each iteration -- so in addition to `list(range(...))` you'll also need `list(filter(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, `filter` just immediately returns a filtered list.

In Python 3, `filter` returns *a filter object*, which can be iterated over to generated filtered content at that later time. Because of this, what the value of `i` is *as evaluated at that later time* matters.

---

Your `i` values aren't getting closed over, so when the filters finally run (after the loop has finished and `list(mylist)` is invoked), all three filters are removing the same `i` value of `2`.

One way to prevent this is to have a function, explicitly binding `i` at invocation time:

```
def filterWithVal(l, i):
    return filter(lambda x: x != i, l)

mylist = range(3)
for i in range(3):
    mylist = filterWithVal(mylist, i)

print(list(mylist))
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @CharlesDuffy I also came up with an idea to force binding of `i` using a partial function:

```
from functools import partial

mylist = range(3)
for i in range(3):
    mylist = filter(partial(lambda x, i: x != i, i), mylist)

print(list(mylist))
```